# How apply correctly gzipped decode string in PHP

Tags: php, base64

I have been trying to decode a gzipped string from a Postman content response, as:

**String to decode:**

> aAAAAB+LCAAAAAAABAAtyjEKgDAMQNGrhMwquPYGHVx0FIfYRqloAm11Ee+uFLfP591o5WLJFIMmNONUYZdW69HUbckhRzTY88KRxQUCAp03zgqiwCnTvLMLnsDpoRDkO4V5hlN+2uDzAmqxWoNoAAAA

**Output:**

> {"Inventarios":[],"MsgId":-1,"MsgStr":"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."}

Then in PHP I was trying to decode a gzipped string and applying also the decode base64, but it did not work fine, showing t his error:

> "Warning: gzdecode(): data error in" path/to/file/

I have this code in PHP:

```
$cad = "aAAAAB+LCAAAAAAABAAtyjEKgDAMQNGrhMwquPYGHVx0FIfYRqloAm11Ee+uFLfP591o5WLJFIMmNONUYZdW69HUbckhRzTY88KRxQUCAp03zgqiwCnTvLMLnsDpoRDkO4V5hlN+2uDzAmqxWoNoAAAA";
$slash = stripslashes($cad);
$b64 = base64_decode($slash);
$abc = utf8_decode($b64);
$gz = gzdecode($abc);  // - gzuncompress   - gzinflate    - gzdecode
echo $gz;
```

How solve this? The problem is with any character as slash \ or spaces, or any parameter that I do not know.

Comment: Why exactly are you removing C slashes and converting to ISO-8859-1 before deflating?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the URL-encoded byte values of your input data after base64 decoding, you got `h%00%00%00%1F%8B%08%00%00…` there - GZip-encoded content should start with `1F 8B 08` though, so you got an extra `h` and three NUL bytes there.

```
$cad = "aAAAAB+LCAAAAAAABAAtyjEKgDAMQNGrhMwquPYGHVx0FIfYRqloAm11Ee+uFLfP591o5WLJFIMmNONUYZdW69HUbckhRzTY88KRxQUCAp03zgqiwCnTvLMLnsDpoRDkO4V5hlN+2uDzAmqxWoNoAAAA";
$cad_base64_decoded = base64_decode($cad);
$gz = gzdecode(substr($cad_base64_decoded, 4));
echo $gz;

// result:
// {"Inventarios":[],"MsgId":-1,"MsgStr":"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."}
```